# mvn clean install not working: Compilation failure

Tags: java, spring, maven, maven-compiler-plugin

I've been having this error since the first time I tried do run the command `mvn clean install`:

```
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
[INFO] Total time:  41.009 s 
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-09-24T11:12:43-03:00 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project accounts: Compilation failure -> [Help 1] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch. 
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging. 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles: 
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

picture:   [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FKUbm.png

My mvn version and my java version (I'll put them in text because the stackoverflow is not letting me add another picture):

```
$ mvn -version

Apache Maven 3.8.6 (84538c9988a25aec085021c365c560670ad80f63) Maven home: C:\apache-maven\apache-maven-3.8.6 Java version: 17.0.4.1, vendor: Azul Systems, Inc., runtime: C:\Java\zulu17.36.17-ca-jdk17.0.4.1-win_x64\zulu17.36.17-ca-jdk17.0.4.1-win_x64 Default locale: pt_BR, platform encoding: Cp1252 OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
```

```
$ java --version

openjdk 17.0.4.1 2022-08-12 LTS OpenJDK Runtime Environment Zulu17.36+17-CA (build 17.0.4.1+1-LTS) OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Zulu17.36+17-CA (build 17.0.4.1+1-LTS, mixed mode, sharing)
```

MY POM.XML FILE: https://github.com/vitoriaacarvalho/mvn-clean-install-error-description/blob/main/pom.xml

I've already tried so many things, and if you want any more details they are probably here: https://github.com/vitoriaacarvalho/mvn-clean-install-error-description I put together this repository to show all of the things I've tried to do, add more pictures, and even the pom.xml code!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, vitoriac! If `org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile)` reports `Compilation failure` on project `accounts`, I'd assume that the issue was in your code.

Comment: Please [don't upload text as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/13447). Edit your question to contain all the information in text form - consider to use the editor's formatting options. Also see [ask] and include the relevant code here, rather than linking to a location where it'll change over time (this would make your question useless for anyone with a similar problem later).

Answer (score -1):

I see that you have configured Maven to run on Java 17 on the IDE and even JAVA_HOME seems to point to the same. However your code needs to be run on JRE 1.8 ?

This I infer from that in your pom.xml you have :

```html
  <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                
                <configuration>
                    <fork>true</fork>
                    <executable>C:\Java\zulu17.36.17-ca-jdk17.0.4.1-win_x64\zulu17.36.17-ca-jdk17.0.4.1-win_x64</executable>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <compilerArgument>-XDignore.symbol.file</compilerArgument>
                </configuration>
 </plugin>
```

In such case:

1. Set your JAVA_HOME to Java 8 or JRE 1.8. If not set source and target to '17' (not 1.7 or 17.0).
2. Your Maven needs to point towards the same, you can check that by `mvn -v` and `java --version` and `echo %JAVA_HOME%` commands
3. If you have a .bat file on Windows for this Maven project, modify its `set` commands to point to right JAVA version.
4. You may also want to add `groupId`, `version` etc tags to maven-compiler-plugin

Correct Way:

```html
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.8</source>
        <target>1.8</target>
        <compilerVersion>1.8</compilerVersion>      
        <fork>true</fork>
        <executable>D:\jdk1.8\bin\javac</executable>                
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

My opinion is, this is caused because of JAVA versions mismatch.

Comment: It is easier to use the `<maven.compiler.release>8</maven.compiler.release>` setup in stead of hard coded directories on a particular machine etc... Furthermore if you really like to create such setup to run Maven with JDK17 while compiling/running tests with JDK 8 you should use toolchains...(Shows how to do it: https://youtu.be/-KbDcJcglPc)

Comment: thank you so much for your help! unfortunately it didn't work for me :( for anyone in the future who has the same problem, I solved it by creating a jar file using eclipse! here's the link I used: https://www.cs.utexas.edu/~scottm/cs307/handouts/Eclipse%20Help/jarInEclipse.htm